# Calling a function inside a function of JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript

```
<table>
  <td><input type="text" name="estimatedMilesPerYear"/></td>
  <td id="demo"></td>
</table>

<script>
function myfunction()
{
   var estMilesPerYear=document.getElementByName("estimatedMilesPerYear")[0].value;
   return estMilesPerYear*12;
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=myFunction();
</script>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Compute</button>
```

This is the code that I have. I need my browser to retrieve the value from the input given by user and display a computed result in the 2nd column of the table.
Is there something wrong with the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have typo in `document.getElementByName`, it should be `getElementsByName`

```
var estMilesPerYear = document.getElementByName("estimatedMilesPerYear")[0].value;
```

Should be

```
var estMilesPerYear = document.getElementsByName("estimatedMilesPerYear")[0].value;
```

and update the innerHTML inside the function itself so that it gets updated whenever function calls

```
function myfunction(){
   var estMilesPerYear=document.getElementsByName("estimatedMilesPerYear")[0].value;
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = estMilesPerYear*12;
}
```

And one more thing, you have again a mistake to call the function, look

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Compute</button>
```

Here function name have capital `F` in `myFunction` whereas you have written "f" in your function definition. So change it as well

```
function myFunction()
```

[JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tevNG/)

Answer (score 0):

Your code to actually set the html of your second column is not within the function that gets called by the button. Try this:

```
function myfunction()
{
   var estMilesPerYear=document.getElementsByName("estimatedMilesPerYear")[0].value;
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = estMilesPerYear*12;
}
```

I would also recommend some error checking to make sure that the user's input is not empty (maybe consider it 0 if it's empty? Or display an error?).

As an aside, your `<script>` tags should go into the `head` tag (or even better, a separate js file referenced in the `head` tag) rather than being arbitrarily pasted in the middle of your html code.

Comment: I did put the js code into a separate js file. And the <script> tag is also in the <head> too. I just wanted the question to be short so I copy pasted the code.

It still doesn't solve the problem though.